# Laravel 5.3 proper way to secure files for download

Tags: php, laravel

I need to download files from my Laravel App. Download can be done for authorized users. I don't want to put this files in public directory.

```
return response()->download('/storage/app/export/file.txt');
```

I use this response in my controller to download file, but I don't know how to refer to file name/path.

My file is located at storage/app/export/file.txt. But I see download method assume the root is storage/app/public (which is linked to public/storage/).

How can I serve file to download from not public disk ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the full path like this:

```
return response()->download(storage_path('app/export/file.txt'));
```